# How to deselect a symbol selected by `elpy-multiedit-python-symbol-at-point` for renaming?

Tags: elpy

I wanted to rename a variable, so I selected all its uses by [`C-c C-e (elpy-multiedit-python-symbol-at-point)`](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#command-elpy-multiedit-python-symbol-at-point) and changed its name. How do I deselect it so that changes in one line don't appear in other lines?

Answer (score 0):

I can deselect by pressing `C-c C-e` again.